# dbUnit xml file format for flat xml dataset

Tags: java, database, junit, dbunit

I'm trying to make the dataset for dbUnit. However, the xml file I used keeps giving me the error: Element type MyTable must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
Can someone tell me why my xml file is incorrect?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <MyTable column1="1", column2="2", column3="3"/>
</dataset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't put commas in your XML fragment.  For example:

```
<dataset>
    <MyTable column1="1" column2="2" column3="3"/>
</dataset>
```